# CURL alternative to the built-in "file_get_contents()" function

Tags: php, curl

So from my understanding this should be fairly simple as I should only need to change the original fileget contents code, and the rest of the script should still work? I have commented out the old file get contents and added the curl below.

after changing from file get contents to cURL the code below does not output

```
    //$data = @file_get_contents("http://www.city-data.com/city/".$cityActualURL."-".$stateActualURL.".html");
//$data = file_get_contents("http://www.city-data.com/city/Geneva-Illinois.html");

//Initialize the Curl session
$ch = curl_init();
$url= "http://www.city-data.com/city/".$cityActualURL."-".$stateActualURL.".html";
//echo "$url<br>";
 $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
//echo $data;

$details = str_replace("\n", "", $data);
$details = str_replace("\r", "", $details);


$detailsBlock = <<<HTML
~<div style='clear:both;'></div><br/><b>(.*?) on our <a href='http://www.city-data.com/top2/toplists2.html'>top lists</a>: </b><ul style='margin:10px;'>(.*?)<div style='bp_bindex'>~
HTML;

$detailsBlock2 = <<<HTML
~<br/><br/><b>(.*?) on our <a href='http://www.city-data.com/top2/toplists2.html'>top lists</a>: </b><ul style='margin:10px;'>(.*?)</ul></td>~
HTML;

$detailsBlock3 = <<<HTML
~<div style='clear:both;'></div><br/><b>(.*?) on our <a href='http://www.city-data.com/top2/toplists2.html'>top lists</a>: </b><ul style='margin:10px;'>(.*?)</ul></td>~
HTML;

preg_match($detailsBlock, $details, $matches);
preg_match($detailsBlock2, $details, $matches2);
preg_match($detailsBlock3, $details, $matches3);

if (isset($matches[2]))
{
    $facts = "<ul style='margin:10px;'>".$matches[2];
}

elseif (isset($matches2[2]))
{
    $facts = "<ul style='margin:10px;'>".$matches2[2];
}

elseif (isset($matches3[2]))
{
    $facts = "<ul style='margin:10px;'>".$matches3[2];
}

else
{
    $facts = "More Information to Come...";
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use cURL instead of file_get_contents?

Comment: @Frits van Campen, since Curl is recommended. Many webserver hosts turn off the option to use file_get_contents();

Comment: So you change the code w/o actually needing to change it? Have fun!

Comment: This used to work fine until the host disabled remote file_get_contents

Comment: What is the question by the way?

Comment: after changing from file get contents to cURL the code below does not output

Comment: Alright. Try `echo 'Curl error:' . curl_error($ch);`
To see if there is a curl error.

Comment: If your hosts disables `file_get_contents`, find a different host. Either they don't know what they're doing, or their tenants don't know what they're doing. Or they're really anal about security and they do have a valid reason for disabling it but then why use PHP at all? _(not saying PHP is insecure, it's just really easy to write some really nice security holes in PHP)._ This probably doesn't help you at all, but I'd go for a socket approach. cURL is .. messy, especially if all you want to do is just fetch some web-service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a problem with your script you need to debug it. For example:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data); die();
```

Then you will get an output what `$data` is. Depending on the output you can further decide where to look next for the cause of the malfunction.

Comment: I get bool(false) using var_dump.

If i echo the variable i get the entire page, but what it will not do is output the arrays

Comment: Okay then it's no wonder that you don't get any data, because your request failed. To learn about what the false return value means, visit the PHP Manual: [`curl_exec`](http://www.php.net/function.curl-exec)

Comment: curl_exec returns false on error. You can get the error message with `curl_error($ch)`.

Answer (score 1):

The following function works great, just pass it a URL.

```
function file_get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

TIP: New lines and carriage returns can be replaced with one line of code.

```
 $details = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"), '', $data);
```